# What is the best web hosting service

Tags: html, web, server, hosting, web-hosting

I am currently making a website on HTML js css...
I want to know what is the best WebHosting service that is cheap

Comment: A lot depends on your requirements, but heroku is probably the easiest for beginners and pretty cheap

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are just starting out, I recommend Firebase Hosting (https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

This would suit you because it is free to get started. As long as it is only you and a few friends trying it out, you will find the cost is $0.

Only when thousands of people are using it, or you are storing hundreds of images or videos, will it start to cost something, and that cost is predictable.